# Mongodb: Text Indexes vs Atlas Search

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

These two features look pretty simmilar, but [Atlas Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/) is fresh and maybe more powerfull.
Is Atlas Search a replacement for Text Indexes in MongoDb? Will [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) be deprecated?
Did I missed some essential difference? Is Atlas Search a proprietar feature of Atlas as cloud platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Atlas Search a proprietary feature of Atlas as cloud platform?

Yes, as of now.

Atlas Search is one of the selling points of Atlas (among many).

> Atlas Search is [newer] and more powerful

Also true.

> Will Text Indexes be deprecated?

I would say unlikely given that on-premise customers then would be left without text search at all, but I am not involved in this decision.

Comment: Are you employee of Atlas?

Comment: Atlas is a product not a company and therefore does not have employees.

Comment: So are you a developer of Atlas?

Comment: No, and my views are mine only and do not represent my current or former employers.

Answer (score 3):

Atlas search is different from Text search, because atlas search uses **Apache Lucene Engine** in the backend for search functionality, which uses an “inverted indexing” to store the data, which makes it much faster due to how data is stored - It saves all keywords like glossary of a book with each page & its keywords.

Some more famous search engines uses same Backend (Apache Lucene) are:

1. Elastic Search
2. Solr

Search engines based on Lucene are very fast than regular text search & has many extra features such as:

1. Faceting (Filters functionality like in e-commerce website).
2. Fuzzy (If we type 1-2 incorrect words it'll still give correct results).
3. Memory based filters
4. Analysers for your needs (which can modify words on the spot while giving results).
5. Multi - Language Support
6. Autocomplete search
7. Much, much more

Atlas search is powerful search engine can search through millions of documents due to it's backend.

So, Yes atlas search is very different from Text Search, it saves alot of time, without need to use 3rd party search engines such as Elastic.

No, text search will not be removed because it can be used for normal applications & search requirements.

**Atlas search is beneficial for projects such as E-Commerce or any application with a-lot of filters & search requirements with millions of documents.**

I My self had used it in Australian E-commerce marketplace as primary search engine.

Comment: Doesn't MongoDb Text indexes also use kind of “inverted indexing”?